# How can I select the best virtual credit card?

Tags: credit-card, services

I'm not allowed to ask for product recommendations, nor for off-site resources, as per closing my prior question:

"Questions seeking product, service recommendations or other off-site resources are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."

So, I wish to use a one-time credit credit card; how do I get the best one?

Comment: Define "best". Without knowing your criteria, no-one can answer.

Comment: Downvoters:  Cut the guy some slack.  Credit card fraud is a major problem for consumers and finding a way to reduce the chance of being defrauded is definitely a personal finance issue.

Answer (score 7):

A  virtual credit card  number (VCCN) is just a service offered by a  regular credit card. Each time that your reach your allocated dollar limit or your expiration date, you have to go in and generate a new number.  It's just a few clicks but it's still an active process.

Google and create a list of credit cards that offer the ability to generate a VCCN.  Then select the card that offers the terms that best meet your needs.  For example, low interest rate, lowest transfer balance rate, highest rebate on purchases, etc.  You're picking the best credit card for you that also offers the VCCN feature.

Comment: Some credit cards offer VCCN services only with some specific browsers on desktops, and perhaps some specific operating systems for phones and mobile devices.

Comment: Determining the method of access would be part of the screening process.

Comment: Ultimately, OP is still looking for a card issuer offering such a service. Once again, the best answer is probably to search. +1 for your kind answer.